# Identifying all the nouns in a string with RoR

Tags: ruby, string

I need a helper that can identify all the nouns on a string.

If the given string is

> I really enjoy eating tomatoes

I should have, as result

> really, enjoy, and tomatoes

If there is a way that I can also idetify the verbs, should be great!

Comment: This is natural language processing. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing_toolkits

Comment: 'really' and 'enjoy' aren't nouns. If you wanted nouns you'd get just 'tomatoes' unless you included pronouns then you'd get 'I'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's links to a Brill tagger written in Ruby on [this page](http://www.markwatson.com/opensource/).